# Reinstalling Windows 10 on tablet without a functional USB port

Tags: windows-10, boot, tablet

I have a tablet (PIPO W2F) with non-functional USB. It also has one SD card slot. I would like to install a system (ideally Windows or ANDROIDx84). Windows 10 already was installed on the device. I'm trying to reinstall it.

I created bootable Windows 10 SD card and started to install it. Everything went OK, but after first restart touch screen stopped work (the driver was deleted).

So right now I have only three buttons (Power, Volume Up, Volume Down) and SD card slot to interact with the device.

Now I'm stuck at "Connect do WiFi" screen. I tried to BOOT it again from SD card, but it doesn't work. Every time I go to "Connect to Wifi" screen.

When I press Power + Volume Up buttons in order to start the device, it appears "Entering DnX mode. Waiting for fastboot command" for a while, but it goes again to "Connect to WiFi" screen.

Do you have any suggestions how to BOOT any OS there?

Comment: Try an OTG cable and microSD reader?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/windows-10-cumulative-update-bricked-my-pipo-w2f/d741d584-c2b6-4686-b7ec-c5c967247971

Comment: @JohnnyVegas You mean cable, that will be plugged into microSD slot and allow me to connect a USB device? I think, that this is not possible. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No -  It's a cable that turns the bottom charge usb port into a usb device port.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I have that cable, but the USB port does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Windows 10 doesn't support this device. You will need some device like a bluetooth keyboard and mouse to drive the tablet until you can install the touchscreen drivers. Even if you managed this I have read that your device will not charge properly when using Windows 10. It will run out of power and never charge again. You need to install Windows 8.1 back on this device before that happens.

My advice: Open a support ticket with the manufacturer or buy a new tablet

Comment: The tablet is officially made for Win8, But I already had installed Win10 there. I'm trying to reinstall it, but it seems that I bricked the device. 
I have a Bluetooth keyboard, but there is no way, how to connect it because I cannot interact with the tablet.
Power supply is not an issue, I removed the battery and replaced it with power supply cable.